# Biased coin: Proof that heads has two third probability for second toss when first toss was heads

Tags: probability, bayesian

From the new book [Weird Math](https://books.google.de/books/about/Weird_Math.html?id=ZTKEtAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y):

> While the Bayesian approach may seem subjective, it can be made
>   rigorous in an abstract sense. For example, suppose you had a coin
>   that was biased. It could be biased by any amount from 0 percent heads
>   to 100 percent heads, with each value equally likely. You toss it
>   once, and it comes up heads. It’s possible to prove that the
>   probability of a head on the second toss is two out of three using
>   Bayesian probability.

**My question**
How do you prove that? Could the same result be reached with the frequentist approach?

Comment: HINT: Let the bias be $p$ which is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$.  Then $P(H_2|H_1) = P(H_2 \cap H_1) / P(H_1)$.  Then evaluate each (the numerator, the denominator, separately) using the law of total probability conditioned on $p$.

Comment: @antkam: Thank you. Could you form an answer for the Bayesian and the frequentist approach?

Comment: Ha, that is a philosophical question.  I am in no way an expert on this but my _impression_ is that a frequentist might say, if you already know the coin could be biased, then 1 sample is not enough to make any useful claim about $P(H_2)$.  Basically this frequentist is hedging and saying, "I don't know enough about $p$ after 1 sample, and I'm not willing to _assume_ something like $p \sim U(0,1)$..."  Another more _reckless_ frequentist might say "Hey 1 sample is fine, and $P(H_2) = 1/1 = 100\%$!"  **But** I could be completely mischaracterizing the frequentist philosophy here.  Sorry!  :)

Comment: @antkam: I understand... could you do the Bayesian part?

Comment: @Downvoter: why the downvote How can I improve the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=P(H)$ and assume that $p$ is uniformly distributed within $[0,1]$.  I.e. the PDF is $f(p) = 1$ for $p \in [0,1]$ (and zero everywhere else).

Let $H_i$ be the event that the $i$th flip is Head.  We want to calculate  $P(H_2|H_1) = P(H_2 \cap H_1) / P(H_1)$.

- Numerator: $P(H_2 \cap H_1) = \int^1_0 P(H_2 \cap H_1 | p)\ f(p)\ dp = \int^1_0 p^2 \cdot 1\  dp = \left[\frac{p^3}{3}\right]^1_0 = \frac{1}{3}$.

  - Note: for any specific value of  $p, P(H_2 \cap H_1 | p) = p^2$ because  flips are independent.
- Denominator: $P(H_1) = \int^1_0 P(H_1 | p)\ f(p)\ dp = \int^1_0 p \cdot 1\ dp = \left[\frac{p^2}{2}\right]^1_0 = \frac{1}{2}$.
- So $P(H_2|H_1) = P(H_2 \cap H_1) / P(H_1) = (\frac{1}{3}) / (\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{2}{3}$.

Note 1: the distribution of the bias itself, $p \sim U(0,1)$, is important.  If other models are assumed, the result will be different.  E.g. if $p$ is one of the three values $\{0, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}$ each with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ (i.e. "First randomly pick one of 3 coins in a bag..."), then $P(H_2 \cap H_1) = \frac{1}{3}(0 + \frac{1}{4} + 1) = \frac{5}{12}$ instead.

Note 2: $P(H_1) = 1/2$ could have been argued based on the symmetry of the bias itself, i.e. based on $f(p)$ being symmetric about $1/2$.  In fact, $P(H_1) = \int^1_0 p\ f(p)\ dp = \mathbb{E}[p]$.

Note 3: For a fair coin $p = 1/2$ and obviously $P(H_2 \cap H_1) = 1/4$.  But despite $f(p)$ being symmetric about $1/2$, i.e. the bias *distribution* being "fair" (equally likely to be biased either way, to equal amounts), nevertheless $P(H_2 \cap H_1) > 1/4$.  This is where the "Bayesian"-ness comes in.

BTW, you may want to work through the example of 3 coins, one with both Heads, one with both Tails, and one fair.  The answer is $5/6$ but more importantly the answer can be calculated with just combinatorics.  The Bayesian idea is to have (or to assume) some prior "bag of (potentially uncountably infinitely many) coins".